# Javascript threading race condition

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout, race-condition, yui

EDIT: I figured out the answer to the original YUI3 question I posted here, but it led to another one and instead of starting a new thread I thought I'd just add it here. Please scroll down for the new question (it's bolded).

Original question:
I'm having some issues creating a JavaScript countdown timer inside a YUI definition, my guess is something to do with object scoping. Here's my code:

```
YUI({combine: true, timeout: 10000}).use("node", function (Y) {
    var timer = new function(){};
    Y.augment(timer, Y.EventTarget);
    timer.on('timer:down', function() {
        Y.log('timer down event fired', 'event');
        Y.Lang.later(1000, Y, timer_trigger());
    });
    timer.on('timer:end', function() {
        Y.log('timer end event fired', 'event');
    });

    var timer_from;

    function startTimer(seconds){ // start a coundown from seconds to 0
        timer_from = seconds;
        timer_trigger();
    }

    function timer_display(){
        var mins = Math.floor(timer_from/60);
        var secs = timer_from - mins*60;
        var secsDisp = secs;
        if(secs<10){
            secsDisp = '0' + secs;
        }
        Y.one('#timer').set('innerHTML', mins + ':' + secsDisp);
    }

    function timer_trigger(){
        Y.log('timer from is: '+timer_from);
        if(timer_from > 0){
            timer_from--;
            timer_display();
            if(timer_from > 0){
                timer.fire('timer:down');
            }
        } else {
            timer.fire('timer:end');
        }
    }

    function initializePage(){
        startTimer(900);
    }


});
```

The error I'm getting is that it doesn't wait the 1000ms like I'm asking it to to call `timer_trigger()` and Safari eventually asks me whether I want to stop running the code. When I do a few seconds after loading the page, the timer is already down to about 3, 4 minutes.
I've also tried using `setTimeout` but that also produces the same result. Can anyone help? I would really appreciate it!

EDIT: 
I actually figured out a solution - this came after hours of trying tons of things, but a few more Google searches can sometimes still produce new results/answers (I found the answer on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664951/jquery-getjson-inside-settimeout-timer), actually).

So apparently my code was creating a race condition, and all I had to do to fix it is this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    timer_trigger();
}, 1000);
```

I looked up race conditions, but it's unclear to me what it means in my case, and how the seemingly trivial change to my code fixed the issue I was having. So the original question in answered, but I'd like to turn this into the question that arose from the answer.

**How does threading in JavaScript work and what cause my race condition, and why did the minor change in code fix the error I had?**

Comment: For future reference, when a question of mine spawns a new one should I start a new thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also note that

```
Y.Lang.later(1000, Y, timer_trigger());
```

executes timer_trigger immediately and passes the return value to Y.Lang.later.  You probably meant

```
Y.Lang.later(1000, Y, timer_trigger);
```

Comment: So that would pass the function to Y.Lang.later, which would execute it 1000ms later, instead of the return value of the function?

Comment: yep.  timer_trigger as it is written above does not include a return statement, so by default it returns undefined.  For Y.Lang.later(1000, Y, timer_trigger()), undefined is passed to Y.Lang.later as the function to execute in one second.  this translates to

    setTimeout(function () { undefined.apply(Y); }, 1000);

which is a runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not a race condition.  The reason the additional call to setTimeout "fixes" your code is because of a logic flaw in `timer_trigger`.  Consider what happens in the case where `timer_from` is 1 when the function is called.  Neither timer:down nor timer:end will be triggered.

```
function timer_trigger(){
    Y.log('timer from is: '+timer_from);
    if(timer_from > 0){      // Since timer_from is 1, the if block is entered
        timer_from--;        // timer_from is 0
        timer_display();
        if(timer_from > 0){  // This block is not entered, but it has no matching else
            timer.fire('timer:down');
        }
    } else {                 // The matching if block was entered, so this is not
        timer.fire('timer:end');
    }
}
```

You added this code:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    timer_trigger();
}, 1000);
```

This causes `timer_trigger` to be called once more with `timer_from` already set to 0, allowing the else block to be executed.

Comment: Wow, I'm shocked I missed that... although my timer_from never got to 1, since I always stopped it around 200 or so. Luke's answer actually explains why my timer_trigger didn't wait 1000ms to fire.