# Auto refresh few attributes of an object using spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Have a table in jsp in which i am populating all object attributes using spring MVC. Getting list of DTO's from backend and putting that DTO list into ModelView .
In jsp we are Iterating that dto list  and displaying in the table. Now the requirement is to come up with auto refresh to update a few attributes of all objects for every 5 seconds. All the attributes has to be retrieved only when user do manual refresh.

Please suggest me some better approach for the same

Comment: you can use ajax and setTimeout  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664951/jquery-getjson-inside-settimeout-timer

Answer (score 1):

JSP makes this job easy by providing you a mechanism where you can make a webpage in such a way that it would refresh automatically after a given interval.

The simplest way of refreshing a web page is using method setIntHeader() of response object. Following is the signature of this method:

```
public void setIntHeader(String header, int headerValue)
```

This method sends back header "Refresh" to the browser along with an integer value which indicates time interval in seconds.

The example below refresh's the page every second updating the time.

```
    <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.text.*,java.util.*"%>
<html>

<head>
<title>Auto Refresh Header Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Auto Refresh Header Example</h2>
<%
// Page will be auto refresh after 1 seconds
response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1);

// Get Current Time
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the key line to refresh: `<%  response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1); %>`

Comment: I need to refresh particular attributes of an object not all objects. Instead of getting all attributes of an object i need to retrieve few attributes.